# Call function to remove an item when link is clicked for each item in list

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function to get a list of items from the database. I want to put a link next to each item where I can call a function to delete the item from the database.

```
function GetCertifications() {
       $("#userCertifications").empty();
       $("#certificationCount").text("Total - 0");
       var userId = $('#userId').val();
       // console.log("Current user Id to get certs " + userId);
       var i = 0;
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'getCertifications', userId: userId }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             i++;
             $("#certificationCount").text("Total - " + i);
             $("#userCertifications").append('<div class="usercert"><li>' + value.certName + '</li><a href="#">X</a></div>');
          });
       });
    }
```

I want to be able to get the value of the list item when the user clicks on the "X" link so I can query the database and delete the item.

```
$(".usercert a").click(function() {
       alert("delete usercert");
    });
```

How do I pass the value into this function? I am using the alert to test and the alert doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add data-id attributes to each a link with id that you want to pass and then add handler on click:

```
$("#userCertifications").append('<div class="usercert"><li>' + value.certName + '</li><a href="#" data-id="' + value.id + '">X</a></div>');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".usercert a").click(function(event) {
        var id= $(event.target).data('id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the link itself to transport that information. Set a delete URL as link `href` or use `data-*` attributes to store the certificate ID or something.

Set the ID in a `data-*` attribute:

```
$( "#userCertifications" ).append( '<div class="usercert"><li>' + value.certName + '</li><a href="#" data-certificate-id="123">X</a></div>' );
```

And retrieve that value in the event handler:

```
$( ".usercert a" ).click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get certificate ID from the link element */
    var certId = parseInt( this.dataset.certificateId ),
        deleteUrl = '//example.org/delete/cert/' + certId;

    console.log( deleteUrl );


    /* …or use the link URL directly */
    var deleteUrl = this.href;

    console.log( deleteUrl );

} );
```